# about:blank opens in Chromium when I type into the dash

Tags: unity, 13.04, google-chrome, unity-dash, chromium

Here's a rather odd problem I'm having. Whenever I open the dash and type into it, Chromium opens up and opens an "about:blank" tab for just about every letter I write into the dash. Why is it doing this and how do I stop it from doing this?

Comment: Have you made any changes to your configuration lately?

Comment: Not that I know of. It's been doing this since recently and I can't say I've made any changes to either Unity or Chromium.

Comment: Mine was doing the same, but opening `about:blank` and a facebook authorisation page.  I tried reauthorising a few times, but the panel goes blank after I log in, so I've just removed the accounts for the time being.

Comment: I think that you are not mentioning the whole process. Is impossible to open a new tab on Chrome searching something in Unity bar. Try to tell us the whole scenario.

Comment: Do you have `gnome-shell` installed?

Comment: I've clarified it now so that it is a more clear question. And yes, I do have gnome-shell installed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fixed. Quite a weird bug. I had to re-login into Google in the "Online Accounts" settings under system settings.

Comment: Had the same issue, fixed through this. Probably needs a bug report on launchpad?

Comment: Did you report this bug?

Answer (score 3):

The workaround is to turn "Include online search results" option off.

Source: http://makairatech.com/blog/ubuntus-dash-opens-chromium-tabs-on-search/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 3):

I believe found a fix.

If you have "Online Accounts" authorized for Ubuntu/unity system (the gear icon in the upper right -> System Settings -> Online Accounts) and there is a access issue (Shows a red gear icon and throws a warning on boot) then this bug happens.

The fix is to re-authorize your existing accounts (Perhaps it occurred because I had changed my google password, and so they became unauthorized?) which can be done from

```
System Settings -> Online Accounts. Correct any errors listed.
```

In any case, re-authorizing my Google accounts seems to have fixed the problem for me. Hope this helps.